# How to retainAll, but regarding doubles in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have two ArrayLists with both having some objects in it:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
Object c = new Object();
Object d = new Object();

ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(a);
list1.add(a);
list1.add(a);
list1.add(b);
list1.add(b);
list1.add(c);
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add(a);
list2.add(a);
list2.add(b);
list2.add(c);
list2.add(c);
list2.add(d);

ArrayList output = retainAllButRegardingDoubles(list1, list2);
```

Now I want to find the elements which intersect with the elements in the other array, but regarding doubles. With 'regarding doubles' I mean this: if list 1 contains three times object A, and list 2 contains twice object A, then the returning array will contain twice object A, because object A occurs at least twice in both arrays.

So I want the outputting list to be as follows:

```
ArrayList {
    a,
    a,
    b,
    c
}
```

'a' occurs in both lists twice, 'b' once and 'c' once.

Is there a library for doing that or do I have to write it myself? If yes, how?

Comment: Explain in more detail what does it mean: regarding doubles.

Comment: Is the element order important to your question or is it just incidentally that you are using `List` instead of `Set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, there is any library support for this particular operation.

As of performing this operation, one way you can go:

```
List retainAllButRegardingDoubles(list1, list2){

  ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList();

  for (Object 0:list1){
     int count1=Collections.frequency(list1, o);
     int count2=Collections.frequency(list2, o);
     int iMin=Math.min(count1,count2);
        for(int i=iMin;i>0;i--){
            result.add(o);
        }
    }
  return result;
 }
```

And this is the most trivial way to retain min of occurence in the two list.

Comment: A simple but working solution with a few lines of code. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static ArrayList retainAllButRegardingDoubles(ArrayList list1, ArrayList list2) {
        //Remove duplicates and get each object only once to improve performance
        Set<?> set1 = new HashSet(list1);
        Set<?> set2 = new HashSet(list2);

        ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList();

        for (Object o : set1){
            //You're adding to the result each element that appears twice at least in list1
            if (Collections.frequency(list1, o) > 1){
                result.add(o);
            }
        }
        for (Object o : set2){
            //You're adding to the result each element that appears twice at least in list2
            if (Collections.frequency(list2, o) > 1){
                result.add(o);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the first list and each time you find a match with some object from the second list, to remove the found object from second list.

```
public List<Object> retainAllButRegardingDoubles(List<Object> list1, List<Object> list2) {
   List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
   for (Object o : list1) {
      if (list2.contains(o)) {
         result.add(o);
         list2.remove(o);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is library to do this. Find first the times an element exists in one list:

```
int times1;
for (Object o: list1) {
    if (o.equals(a)) {
        times1++;
    }
}
```

Then do the same for the second list:

```
int times2;
for (Object o: list1) {
    if (o.equals(a)) {
        times2++;
    }
}

if (min(times1, times2) > 0) {
    int times = min(times1, times2);
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        list.add(a);
    }
}
```

Of course you have to adjust the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
         List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
         list1.add("object1");
         list1.add("object1");
         list1.add("object3");
         list1.add("object5");
         list1.add("object10");

         List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
         list2.add("object1");
         list2.add("object1");
         list2.add("object2");
         list2.add("object6");
         list2.add("object10");

         List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
         list3.add("object1");
         list3.add("object1");
         list3.add("object3");
         list3.add("object7");
         list3.add("object10");

         List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
         list4.add("object1");
         list4.add("object1");
         list4.add("object2");
         list4.add("object8");  
         list4.add("object10");

         Collection<List<String>> collection = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
         collection.add(list1);
         collection.add(list2);
         collection.add(list3);
         collection.add(list4);

         List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
         result =((ArrayList<List<String>>) collection).get(0);

         for (int i=1;i< collection.size(); i++) {           
            result.retainAll(((ArrayList<List<String>>) collection).get(i));            
         }      


         for(String s:result){
             System.out.println(s);
         }
```